# ¿Como poner estatico el encabezado de una tabla html con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo la siguiente table:

```js
$('.listado_volumen_negocio > tr').remove();
var listado_volumen_negocio = $('.listado_volumen_negocio');
var response = {
  "data": [{
      "Nivel_Codigo": 1,
      "Nombre": "Juan",
      "VNIndividual": 4,
      "VNRed": 7,
      "Titulo": "10"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    }
  ]
};
$.each(response.data, function(index, value) {
  $('<tr/>')
    .append($('<td style="font-size: 11px;"/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').append("<p style='margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px;'>" + value.Nivel_Codigo + "</p>" + "<p style='margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px;'>" + value.Nombre + "</p>"))
    .append($('<td style="font-size: 11px;"/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(moneda(value.VNIndividual)))
    .append($('<td style="font-size: 11px;"/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(moneda(value.VNRed)))
    .append($('<td style="font-size: 11px;"/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(value.Titulo))
    .appendTo(listado_volumen_negocio);
});


function moneda(any) {
  return "$" + any;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card data-table nueva-table freeze-table">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="nuevo-td" rowspan="2" style="font-size: 11px;">Nombre</thd>
          <th colspan="2">Volumen de negocio</th>
          <th rowspan="2" class="label-cell nuevo-th" style="font-size: 11px;">Titulo</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="nuevo-td" style="font-size: 11px;">Individual</th>
        <td class="label-cell nuevo-th" style="font-size: 11px;">Red</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="listado_volumen_negocio" class="listado_volumen_negocio">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

el tbody lo lleno dinamicamente.

Visualmente queda de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al seguir bajando en la tabla el encabezado se pierde y quiero que mientras vaya bajando la tabla el encabezado siga el registro para no perderlo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograrlo apliqué los siguientes cambios:

1. Para dejar algo fijo usa css, mediante `position: fixed` que hace que el posicionamiento sea absoluto y
   `top: 0` que nos pone en la parte superior
2. Utiliza el evento `window.onscroll` para detectar el movimiento del ratón
3. Usa la propiedad `window.pageYOffset` para saber el desplazamiento vertical
4. Obten el elemento html del encabezado usando `document.getElementById("myHeader")`.
5. obten la posición vertical del encabezado mediante la propiedad `offsetTop`.
6. Agrega y quita la clase de css que deja el encabezado fijo mediante el uso de `elementoweb.classList.add("nombre de la clase");` y `eleementoweb.classList.remove("nombre de la clase")` respectivamente.
7. Para mejorar la apariencia, y como en tu caso usas una tabla, duplicamos el encabezado pero lo ponemos invisible para que no se descuadren las posiciones de la demás tabla.

```js
//$('.listado_volumen_negocio > tr').remove();
var listado_volumen_negocio = $('.listado_volumen_negocio');
var response = {
  "data": [{
      "Nivel_Codigo": 1,
      "Nombre": "Juan",
      "VNIndividual": 4,
      "VNRed": 7,
      "Titulo": "10"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    },
    {
      "Nivel_Codigo": 2,
      "Nombre": "Pablo",
      "VNIndividual": 5,
      "VNRed": 8,
      "Titulo": "11"
    }
  ]
};
$.each(response.data, function(index, value) {
  $('<tr>')
    .append($('<td style="font-size: 11px;"/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').append("<p style='margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px;'>" + value.Nivel_Codigo + "</p>" + "<p style='margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px;'>" + value.Nombre + "</p>"))
    .append($('<td style="font-size: 11px;"/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(moneda(value.VNIndividual)))
    .append($('<td style="font-size: 11px;"/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(moneda(value.VNRed)))
    .append($('<td style="font-size: 11px;"/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(value.Titulo))
    .appendTo(listado_volumen_negocio);
});


function moneda(any) {
  return "$" + any;
}



/////////////// header ////////////
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");

  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");

  }
}
```

```css
/* estilo del encabezado */

.header {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}


/* Contenido */

.content {
  padding: 10px;
}


/* esta clase se agrega con js */

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.tdoculto {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card data-table nueva-table freeze-table">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="header" id="myHeader">
      <tr>
        <th class="nuevo-td" rowspan="2" style="font-size: 11px;">Nombre</th>
        <th colspan="2">Volumen de negocio</th>
        <th rowspan="2" class="label-cell nuevo-th" style="font-size: 11px;">Titulo</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="nuevo-td" style="font-size: 11px;">Individual</th>
        <td class="label-cell nuevo-th" style="font-size: 11px;">Red</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="listado_volumen_negocio" class="listado_volumen_negocio">
      <tr class="tdoculto">
        <td rowspan="2" style="font-size: 11px;">Nombre</td>
        <td colspan="2">Volumen de negocio</td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="label-cell nuevo-th" style="font-size: 11px;">Titulo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tdoculto">
        <td class="nuevo-td" style="font-size: 11px;">Individual</td>
        <td class="label-cell nuevo-th" style="font-size: 11px;">Red</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```